# Storing big numbers as they are

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I'm using java and Apache derby to create a project that deals with big numbers. Everything is going fine except when i store big numbers. 
For eg. when i save 1000000000 through my java class to a derby table, it automatically becomes 1.0E9. When this value is retrieved in another form it is displayed like 1.0E9. How can I stop this? I'm using float data type to do this. 
In other words, how can I save 1000000000 as 1000000000 and not 1.0E9

Comment: Use `BigInteger` class. If you can't, then handle it as a `String` =\ (sad face because it shouldn't be a `String` and it is an ugly solution).

Comment: @erencan I didn't know Integers could roll both ways.  |=^)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what is the case where you need to use `String` instead of `BigInteger` if you need mathematical operations?

Comment: @erencan Yeah, at that point they're really just rolling their own arbitrary precision library, backed by `String`s... ick.

Comment: @erencan maybe the database driver does not support saving `BigInteger` so you should store/retrieve the data as `String` and handle conversion from/to `BigInteger` from this `String`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza then `BigInteger#toString()` can be used.

Comment: @erencan still you have to use `String` instead of using `BigInteger` only... that was my point from the beginning, and I do not like doing these hacks that *polute* the code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you suggest to store numbers in String and also implement mathematical operations for numbers which is bigger than 2^64-1 to avoid code pollution.

Comment: @erencan I never suggested that. I can't read that direct suggestion on none of my comments.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how do you operate mathematical operations on `String`? OP needs numbers and mathematics behind them?

Comment: @erencan one more time: I **never** said to do math operations in plain `String`s. I was referring to storage of data using `BigInteger`, if you can't then use `String`. Even the question title is ***Storing** big numbers as they are*, not *do foo math operations with big numbers*. Please **do not** over complicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like above said you could use a BigInteger or you could just covert 1.0E9 to what the number actually is. 1.0 x 10^9.

Answer (score 0):

1.0e9 is the same as 1000000000; it's just a representation issue. You just have to apply the proper formatters when transforming it to a string.

Two things that would make this easier are to use the `NUMERIC` column type in Derby, and also use either `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` data types in your Java code, or possibly a `long` if you're confident that the long can hold the values in your problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
//...
//...
//...
BigInteger store = new BigInteger("1000000000");
```